# How to remove element on delete without refreshing page jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to remove the item from page after successfully deletion from database with php and jquery? I have a list with users. When some of them is deleted I want just to remove it from page.
This is jquery part

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.delete').click(function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest('media-heading');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'friendRemove.php',
            data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + $(this).attr('id'),
            beforeSend: function () {
                parent.animate({
                    'backgroundColor': '#fb6c6c'
                }, 300);
            },

        });
    });

    $('.delete').confirm({
        text: "Are you sure?",
        title: "Please Confirm",

        confirmButton: "Yes",
        cancelButton: "No",
        post: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        cancelButtonClass: "btn-default",
        dialogClass: "modal-dialog modal-lg"
    });
});
```

I have tried to put success function in ajax part but nothing happen. This is what I tried.

```
success: function () {
    parent.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

HTML part

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="pull-left">';
        <img class="media-object dp img-circle" src="img/no-image-fun.gif"></div>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">username</h4> <a href="" class="delete" id="'.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-times pull-right"></i></a>
        <h5>images</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would you please share the html code ?

Comment: HTML part is added to the question

Comment: Don't use trailing commas in _ajax_, IE don't like it, this may not work on some IE versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is wrong, it's missing `.` class selector to the `closest`

```
var parent = $(this).closest('media-heading'); // <-- Missing . before classname
```

Use

```
var parent = $(this).closest('.media-heading');
```

Comment: Yes, now is working. But it is delete the user on click and doesn't wait for `Yes` on `confirm` function..

Comment: @JordanVit I guess you're using a plugin/library for custom confirm box which must have provided the true/Ok callback, create a function and call it as callback with the code of `.delete` event handler. Hope that's clear.

Comment: Yes, it is custom and I use the function as it is shown in the demo of the plugin but still.. Ok, this is another problem thank's for helping me on this one.. I will try to fix the confirm problem.